# Why does the return in this function happens before indexDB returns the requested value?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have a very basic indexedDB with one key. I would like to retrieve this value to perform an operation. Unfortunately, the function that is supposed to do it returns `undefined` before indexedDB could return the value.

Here are the functions:

```js
const getValue = async () => {
   const res = await IndexedDB.get(1)
   return console.log("res", res) // displayed before "res" has finished
};
  

export default class IndexedDB {
  static createDB() {
    const request = indexedDB.open("myApp", 1);
    request.onupgradeneeded = (e) => {
      const db = e.target.result;
      return db.createObjectStore("myData", { autoIncrement: true });
    };
  }

  static addData(data) {
    const db = indexedDB.open("myApp", 1);
    db.onsuccess = (e) => {
      const request = e.target.result
        .transaction(["myData"], "readwrite")
        .objectStore("myData")
        .add(data);
      request.onsuccess = (res) => res.target.result;
      request.onerror = (err) => err
    };
  }

  static get(key) {
    const db = indexedDB.open("myApp", key);
    db.onsuccess = (e) => {
      const request = e.target.result
        .transaction(["myData"])
        .objectStore("myData")
        .get(key);
      request.onsuccess = (res) => res.target.result;
      request.onerror = (err) => err
    };
  }

}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: `get()` doesn't return a promise, there's nothing for `await` to wait for.

Comment: `get()` doesn't even return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IndexedDb.get` function is not async, but you are awaiting it for some reason?

Change it to:

```js
static get(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const db = indexedDB.open("myApp", key);
    db.onsuccess = (e) => {
      const request = e.target.result
        .transaction(["myData"])
        .objectStore("myData")
        .get(key);
      request.onsuccess = (res) => resolve(res.target.result);
      request.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IndexedDb.get` has some async operations `indexedDB.open("myApp", key)`. To handle this kind of sync function you need to either use a promise or you can use a callback function.

Using **Promise**

```
static get(key) {
    let resolve, reject;
    const promise = new Promise((re, rj) => { resolve = re; reject = rj; }),
        db = indexedDB.open("myApp", key);
    db.onsuccess = (e) => {
      const request = e.target.result
        .transaction(["myData"])
        .objectStore("myData")
        .get(key);
      request.onsuccess = (res) => resolve(res.target.result);
      request.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
    };
    return promise;
}
```

Using **Callbacks**

```
static get(key, successCB, errorCB) {
    db.onsuccess = (e) => {
      const request = e.target.result
        .transaction(["myData"])
        .objectStore("myData")
        .get(key);
      request.onsuccess = successCB;
      request.onerror = errorCB;
    };
}
// get(key, (res) => {}, (err) => {})
```